# Adding Dynamic text to a Coin Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using a coin-slider plugin for a rotating banner and would like to know how to include dynamic text that should change when the banner changes. Found a post here that described what I wanted to do but not sure of the code alterations that need to be made. Would like to be walked through the process so I can learn to do it on my own. Tried to include all the code so you ca run it and see what I see on my screen but its not working properly. Sorry

```js
/** coin slider js**/
/**
 * Coin Slider - Unique jQuery Image Slider
 * @version: 1.0 - (2010/04/04)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.2 or later 
 * @author Ivan Lazarevic
 * Examples and documentation at: http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/
 
 * Licensed under MIT licence:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
**/

(function($) {

 var params   = new Array;
 var order  = new Array;
 var images  = new Array;
 var links  = new Array;
 var linksTarget = new Array;
 var titles  = new Array;
 var interval = new Array;
 var imagePos = new Array;
 var appInterval = new Array; 
 var squarePos = new Array; 
 var reverse  = new Array;
 
 $.fn.coinslider= $.fn.CoinSlider = function(options){
  
  init = function(el){
    
   order[el.id]   = new Array(); // order of square appereance
   images[el.id]  = new Array();
   links[el.id]  = new Array();
   linksTarget[el.id] = new Array();
   titles[el.id]  = new Array();
   imagePos[el.id]  = 0;
   squarePos[el.id] = 0;
   reverse[el.id]  = 1;      
    
   params[el.id] = $.extend({}, $.fn.coinslider.defaults, options);
      
   // create images, links and titles arrays
   $.each($('#'+el.id+' img'), function(i,item){
    images[el.id][i]   = $(item).attr('src');
    links[el.id][i]   = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('href') : '';
    linksTarget[el.id][i]  = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('target') : '';
    titles[el.id][i]   = $(item).next().is('span') ? $(item).next().html() : '';
    $(item).hide();
    $(item).next().hide();
   });   
   

   // set panel
   $(el).css({
    'background-image':'url('+images[el.id][0]+')',
    'width': params[el.id].width,
    'height': params[el.id].height,
    'position': 'relative',
    'background-position': 'top left'
   }).wrap("<div class='coin-slider' id='coin-slider-"+el.id+"' />"); 
   
    
   // create title bar
   $('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-title' id='cs-title-"+el.id+"' style='position: absolute; bottom:0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;'></div>");
      
   $.setFields(el);
   
   if(params[el.id].navigation)
    $.setNavigation(el);
   
   $.transition(el,0);
   $.transitionCall(el);
    
  }
  
  // squares positions
  $.setFields = function(el){
   
   tWidth = sWidth = parseInt(params[el.id].width/params[el.id].spw);
   tHeight = sHeight = parseInt(params[el.id].height/params[el.id].sph);
   
   counter = sLeft = sTop = 0;
   tgapx = gapx = params[el.id].width - params[el.id].spw*sWidth;
   tgapy = gapy = params[el.id].height - params[el.id].sph*sHeight;
   
   for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
    gapx = tgapx;
    
     if(gapy > 0){
      gapy--;
      sHeight = tHeight+1;
     } else {
      sHeight = tHeight;
     }
    
    for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){ 

     if(gapx > 0){
      gapx--;
      sWidth = tWidth+1;
     } else {
      sWidth = tWidth;
     }

     order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
     counter++;
     
     if(params[el.id].links)
      $('#'+el.id).append("<a href='"+links[el.id][0]+"' class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></a>");
     else
      $('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></div>");
        
     // positioning squares
     $("#cs-"+el.id+i+j).css({ 
      'background-position': -sLeft +'px '+(-sTop+'px'),
      'left' : sLeft ,
      'top': sTop
     });
    
     sLeft += sWidth;
    }

    sTop += sHeight;
    sLeft = 0;     
     
   }
   
   
   $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
    $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();
   });
  
   $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
    $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
   }); 
   
   $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
    $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();
   });
  
   $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
    $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
   }); 
   
   if(params[el.id].hoverPause){ 
    $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
     params[el.id].pause = true;
    });
   
    $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
     params[el.id].pause = false;
    }); 
    
    $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
     params[el.id].pause = true;
    });
   
    $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
     params[el.id].pause = false;
    }); 
   }
     
   
  };
    
  
  $.transitionCall = function(el){
  
   clearInterval(interval[el.id]); 
   delay = params[el.id].delay + params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph*params[el.id].sDelay;
   interval[el.id] = setInterval(function() { $.transition(el)  }, delay);
   
  }
  
  // transitions
  $.transition = function(el,direction){
   
   if(params[el.id].pause == true) return;
   
   $.effect(el);
   
   squarePos[el.id] = 0;
   appInterval[el.id] = setInterval(function() { $.appereance(el,order[el.id][squarePos[el.id]])  },params[el.id].sDelay);
     
   $(el).css({ 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });
   
   if(typeof(direction) == "undefined")
    imagePos[el.id]++;
   else
    if(direction == 'prev')
     imagePos[el.id]--;
    else
     imagePos[el.id] = direction;
  
   if  (imagePos[el.id] == images[el.id].length) {
    imagePos[el.id] = 0;
   }
   
   if (imagePos[el.id] == -1){
    imagePos[el.id] = images[el.id].length-1;
   }
 
   $('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
   $('#cs-button-'+el.id+"-"+(imagePos[el.id]+1)).addClass('cs-active');
   
   if(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]){
    $('#cs-title-'+el.id).css({ 'opacity' : 0 }).animate({ 'opacity' : params[el.id].opacity }, params[el.id].titleSpeed);
    $('#cs-title-'+el.id).html(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);
   } else {
    $('#cs-title-'+el.id).css('opacity',0);
   }    
    
  };
  
  $.appereance = function(el,sid){

   $('.cs-'+el.id).attr('href',links[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]).attr('target',linksTarget[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);

   if (squarePos[el.id] == params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph) {
    clearInterval(appInterval[el.id]);
    return;
   }

   $('#cs-'+el.id+sid).css({ opacity: 0, 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });
   $('#cs-'+el.id+sid).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
   squarePos[el.id]++;
   
  };
  
  // navigation
  $.setNavigation = function(el){
   // create prev and next 
   $(el).append("<div id='cs-navigation-"+el.id+"'></div>");
   $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
   
   $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-prev-"+el.id+"' class='cs-prev'>prev</a>");
   $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-next-"+el.id+"' class='cs-next'>next</a>");
   $('#cs-prev-'+el.id).css({
    'position'  : 'absolute',
    'top'  : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
    'left'  : 0,
    'z-index'  : 1001,
    'line-height': '30px',
    'opacity' : params[el.id].opacity
   }).click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.transition(el,'prev');
    $.transitionCall(el);  
   }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });
 
   $('#cs-next-'+el.id).css({
    'position'  : 'absolute',
    'top'  : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
    'right'  : 0,
    'z-index'  : 1001,
    'line-height': '30px',
    'opacity' : params[el.id].opacity
   }).click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.transition(el);
    $.transitionCall(el);
   }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });
  
   // image buttons
   $("<div id='cs-buttons-"+el.id+"' class='cs-buttons'></div>").appendTo($('#coin-slider-'+el.id));

   
   for(k=1;k<images[el.id].length+1;k++){
    $('#cs-buttons-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' class='cs-button-"+el.id+"' id='cs-button-"+el.id+"-"+k+"'>"+k+"</a>");
   }
   
   $.each($('.cs-button-'+el.id), function(i,item){
    $(item).click( function(e){
     $('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
     $(this).addClass('cs-active');
     e.preventDefault();
     $.transition(el,i);
     $.transitionCall(el);    
    })
   }); 
   
   $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id+' a').mouseout(function(){
    $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
    params[el.id].pause = false;
   });      

   $("#cs-buttons-"+el.id).css({
    'left'   : '50%',
    'margin-left'  : -images[el.id].length*15/2-5,
    'position'  : 'relative'
    
   });
   
    
  }




  // effects
  $.effect = function(el){
   
   effA = ['random','swirl','rain','straight'];
   if(params[el.id].effect == '')
    eff = effA[Math.floor(Math.random()*(effA.length))];
   else
    eff = params[el.id].effect;

   order[el.id] = new Array();

   if(eff == 'random'){
    counter = 0;
      for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
       for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){ 
        order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
      counter++;
       }
      } 
    $.random(order[el.id]);
   }
   
   if(eff == 'rain') {
    $.rain(el);
   }
   
   if(eff == 'swirl')
    $.swirl(el);
    
   if(eff == 'straight')
    $.straight(el);
    
   reverse[el.id] *= -1;
   if(reverse[el.id] > 0){
    order[el.id].reverse();
   }

  }

   
  // shuffle array function
  $.random = function(arr) {
      
    var i = arr.length;
    if ( i == 0 ) return false;
    while ( --i ) {
       var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
       var tempi = arr[i];
       var tempj = arr[j];
       arr[i] = tempj;
       arr[j] = tempi;
     }
  } 
  
  //swirl effect by milos popovic
  $.swirl = function(el){

   var n = params[el.id].sph;
   var m = params[el.id].spw;

   var x = 1;
   var y = 1;
   var going = 0;
   var num = 0;
   var c = 0;
   
   var dowhile = true;
      
   while(dowhile) {
    
    num = (going==0 || going==2) ? m : n;
    
    for (i=1;i<=num;i++){
     
     order[el.id][c] = x+''+y;
     c++;

     if(i!=num){
      switch(going){
       case 0 : y++; break;
       case 1 : x++; break;
       case 2 : y--; break;
       case 3 : x--; break;
      
      }
     }
    }
    
    going = (going+1)%4;

    switch(going){
     case 0 : m--; y++; break;
     case 1 : n--; x++; break;
     case 2 : m--; y--; break;
     case 3 : n--; x--; break;  
    }
    
    check = $.max(n,m) - $.min(n,m);   
    if(m<=check && n<=check)
     dowhile = false;
         
   }
  }

  // rain effect
  $.rain = function(el){
   var n = params[el.id].sph;
   var m = params[el.id].spw;

   var c = 0;
   var to = to2 = from = 1;
   var dowhile = true;


   while(dowhile){
    
    for(i=from;i<=to;i++){
     order[el.id][c] = i+''+parseInt(to2-i+1);
     c++;
    }
    
    to2++;
    
    if(to < n && to2 < m && n<m){
     to++; 
    }
    
    if(to < n && n>=m){
     to++; 
    }
    
    if(to2 > m){
     from++;
    }
    
    if(from > to) dowhile= false;
    
   }   

  }

  // straight effect
  $.straight = function(el){
   counter = 0;
   for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
    for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){ 
     order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
     counter++;
    }
    
   }
  }

  $.min = function(n,m){
   if (n>m) return m;
   else return n;
  }
  
  $.max = function(n,m){
   if (n<m) return m;
   else return n;
  }  
 
 this.each (
  function(){ init(this); }
 );
 

 };
 
 
 // default values
 $.fn.coinslider.defaults = { 
  width: 847, // width of slider panel
  height: 372, // height of slider panel
  spw: 7, // squares per width
  sph: 5, // squares per height
  delay: 5000, // delay between images in ms
  sDelay: 30, // delay beetwen squares in ms
  opacity: 0.7, // opacity of title and navigation
  titleSpeed: 500, // speed of title appereance in ms
  effect: '', // random, swirl, rain, straight
  navigation: true, // prev next and buttons
  links : true, // show images as links 
  hoverPause: true // pause on hover  
 }; 
 
})(jQuery);

/** dynamic text code**/
setInterval(function () {
    $('#titles').fadeOut(5000, function () {
        $(this).find('p:eq(' + i + ')').show().siblings().hide()
            .end().end().fadeIn(5000, function () {
            i++;
            if (i === imgs.length) {
                i = 0
            };
        });
    });
}, 5000)
```

```css
.coin-slider { overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; position: relative; width: 847px; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: auto;}
.coin-slider a{ text-decoration: none; outline: none; border: none; }

.cs-buttons { font-size: 0px; padding: 10px; float: left; }
.cs-buttons a { margin-left: 5px; height: 10px; width: 10px; float: left; border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; color: #B8C4CF; text-indent: -1000px; }
.cs-active { background-color: #B8C4CF; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-title { width: 545px; padding: 10px; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-prev { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px 5px;
  left: 10px !important;
 display:block;
 width:31px;
 height:30px;
 background:url(left-arrow.png) no-repeat;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 border:0;
 opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
} 

.cs-next { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px 5px; 
 display:block;
 width:31px;
 height:30px;
 background:url(right-arrow.png) no-repeat;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 border:0;
 opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.continer {
  position: relative;
}
body {
    background-image:url('../img/bg_sub-empty.jpg');
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
#contentBox {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 73%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/******************************************
                 HERO
******************************************/
.hero {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('../img/banner-bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #55104e;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.eventSlider {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 12%;
  left: 5%;
  
}

.banner1 {
  height: 472px;
  background-color: orange;

}
.banner-bg1{
  height: 472px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.titles p {
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="contentBox">
    <div class="container hero">
      <div class="eventSlider">
        <div id="slider"style="position:relative; z-index: 20;"> 
          <div class="titles" style="z-index: 40;">
            <p>this is some text </p>
            <p>this is some more text</p>
            <p>this is even more text</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a class"banner1" href="#"><img src="img/banner.png" alt="Photo" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/placeholder.jpg" alt="Photo" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/placeholder.jpg" alt="Photo" /></a>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <script> $('#slider').coinslider(); </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have problems with the Dynamic Text or does the JS not run at all?

Comment: Having problems with the dynamic text. The JS runs fine. Is there a way that I can include all my files so you can see what i see in my brower? Tried to do a fiddle but I don't know how to include images

Comment: I don't know actually. Just include some Google Pictures, I guess. They should be online all the time...

Comment: here's the url to a fiddle I created, however the coin-slider is not working https://jsfiddle.net/s81uxjw7/2/

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of problems with the script:

1. The first mistake, which caused Javascript to Stop executing the Script, was that you called the "coinslider" function, before the whole coinslider Library was known to the browser. Moving the function call to after the function declaration resolved this problem.
2. You used the wrong HTML structure for the script. Apparently the coinslider script needs a structure like this:

```html
<div class="eventSlider">
  <div id="slider" style="position:relative; z-index: 20;">
    <div>
      <a class "banner1" href="#">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqhIMgxbp1HKtnELI_riTfcla8sJt7Pio-vMmAC50bcw3yuext" alt="Photo" />
        <span>this is some text </span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCy7AFWUM-FeqYfl6hCLJxs2zIlyMyPMiZrW6IUGiL-T0i32CDxQ" alt="Photo" />
        <span>this is some more text</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0o-zuf1srGMCLCXmkBr3S3tmqJL3ygxsgK5dZoG6XlXcnsG1A8A" alt="Photo" />
        <span>this is even more text</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the script needs every text right beside the Picture you want to use it for.

Also the Text cannot be placed into a DIV container. This will cause the script to fail. Just use SPAN instead.

Otherwise you used it all correctly.

**See the full / running version here:** https://jsfiddle.net/s81uxjw7/3/